# Strange change of Context in following example

Tags: javascript, html, lexical-scope

I tried the following example but the 2 types console is returning 2 different results. I expected my custom object to be returned on both occasions, but result seems a bit strange. Can someone explain the outcome?

```html
<html> 
<head> </head> 
<body> 
<script>
var obj1 = {
 printThis: function() {
  console.log(this);
 }
};

obj1.printThis(); //refers to my custom object

var func1 = obj1.printThis;
func1(); //refers to window object
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Result:**

While the first console returns **Custom Object**, 2nd returns the **Window Object** (though at StackOverflow due to their own anonymous function wrapper some other object it may refer to). But, in Chrome the 2nd console provides reference to the Window Object.

Comment: Second function call is closure, where this refer to global object reference. First function call is refer to current object instance.

Comment: @VIJAYABALDHANAPAL - But, it is running from inside custom object, then 'this' must have referred to the custom object. Why referring to 'window' object?

Comment: Second function call is in global space. obj1.printThis()->This refers current object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is different because of the context or environment in which the function (`printThis`) is executing.
In first case, function's execution context is inside of `obj1`. But in the second case, function is executing in the global context or environment.

If you want to execute the second function call to be executed inside `obj1`, you have to bind it explicitly like: `obj1.printThis.bind(obj1)`.

```js
var obj1 = {
 printThis: function() {
  console.log(this);
 }
};

obj1.printThis(); 

var func1 = obj1.printThis.bind(obj1);
func1();
```